How to publish hyperfile with several tables to Tableau Server
I have a very common setup: A database with one key table and several other tables, each refers to the key table with foreign key.
I can create a Tableau hyper file from this database but publishing it via Tableau API fails with an error:

Could not make a data source from the given Hyper file: it must contain exactly one fact table.

If I leave only two tables: the key table and one of the other tables everything works.
I tried to create a fake fact table that has foreign keys to all other tables to satisfy the requirement of a single fact table like below:
     counter = 0           
     for table in tables:
         idColumnName = f'id{counter}'
         counter = counter + 1

         sql = f'''ALTER TABLE "{datasourceName}"."fake_table" ADD ASSUMED FOREIGN KEY 
                                           ({idColumnName}) REFERENCES  "{datasourceName}"."{table}" ( "id" )'''
         connection.execute_command(sql)

but now the publishing step fails with no error message, just 400 error code.
Is there any way to publish an extract for my setup: one key table and several value tables ?

Are you using table joins or relationship join?

@Bernardo I edited the question with code that shows the table relationships. According to Table API documentation this should work but it does not. Also joins are in the workbook, My question is about the datasource (which comes before workbooks).
